# ogr2ogr with GDAL 2.4 not reprojecting correctly

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, sql-server-spatial

I have downloaded the latest OSGeo4w (GDAL 2.4) and GDAL 2.4 (from GIS Internals site) but I cant get the below command to correctly reproject the shapes in either application.

I used the command below

```
ogr2ogr.exe  -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=blah;database=blah;trusted_connection=yes;" "MSSQL:server=blah;database=blah;trusted_connection=yes;" -overwrite -sql "select databaseName,objectid,shape from gm.dbo.stg_polygon" -s_srs "EPSG:26910" -t_srs "EPSG:102008" -lco "UPLOAD_GEOM_FORMAT=wkt" -lco "GEOM_TYPE=geometry" -lco "GEOMETRY_NAME=shape" -nlt POLYGON  -nln "stg_ztest"
```

It always returns a spatial SRID = 32768.  We are loading into SQL Server 2017.This works correctly using OSGeo4W shell (from QGIS 2.18) in GDAL 2.2.1

Answer (score 4):

The other GDAL is somehow missing the definitions of ESRI projections. You can read the Proj string from your OSGeo4W installation and use that as -t_srs

```
gdalsrsinfo epsg:102008

PROJ.4 : +proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs
```

This command should make correct transformatiton for your coordinates:

```
ogr2ogr.exe  -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=blah;database=blah;trusted_connection=yes;" "MSSQL:server=blah;database=blah;trusted_connection=yes;" -overwrite -sql "select databaseName,objectid,shape from gm.dbo.stg_polygon" -s_srs "EPSG:26910" -t_srs "+proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs" -lco "UPLOAD_GEOM_FORMAT=wkt" -lco "GEOM_TYPE=geometry" -lco "GEOMETRY_NAME=shape" -nlt POLYGON  -nln "stg_ztest"
```